# Read Term store in SP 2013 and build custom tree

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, term-store

I try to read Term store and build custom tree structure using CSOM in sharepoint 2013.

i can able to get the terms from term set

```
var terms = termSet.GetAllTerms();
            clientContext.Load(terms);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

i get the individual terms,but how do i build tree structure from these terms.

Comment: You want to build a tree like navigation menu or what?

Comment: yes want to build a tree from Termstore

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Termstore is already in tree structure. (https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/_taeggxqgqNw/TUxiFzGEA_I/AAAAAAAABtM/aEy9FoH0rgg/Metadata%20Texanomy.png.jpg)

Comment: i have requirement to read the term store in console application or web api (.Net projetct not provider hosted app)

Comment: Check this out from similar question
[Returning a SharePoint 2013 termset in a tree structure using CSOM](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/178792/49726)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web application use jquery plugin like jquery fileTree. 
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/

Comment: its not web application, its REST service

Comment: What you mean by tree structure inside a service? Isn't it already a Json object?