# Returning a SharePoint 2013 termset in a tree structure using CSOM

Tags: 2013, csom, term-store

Is there's a way to Return a SharePoint 2013 termset in a tree structure using CSOM ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that produce this XML structure:

```
<Field DisplayName="Doc Type" Type="Managed Metadata" InternalName="Doc_x0020_Type">
    <Value>-1;#Term A|8e3217b1-f15d-4049-83f0-02b7cb168cb3
      <Value>
        <Value>-1;#Term A1|3f0cc693-4488-41ec-9158-972e9fac140e
            <Value>-1;#Term A11|3f0cc693-4488-41ec-9158-972e9fac140e</Value>
            <Value>-1;#Term A12|50fe67ae-8ced-471d-a1b1-adeb3266fb45</Value>
        </Value>
      </Value>
    </Value>
    <Value>-1;#Term B|6f45adfe-c64a-481e-bf29-a8f96d8c1791
        <Value>-1;#Term B1|a0a89c0f-4c1b-489e-9b24-bf2648fa36d6</Value>
        <Value>-1;#Term B2|196a4b08-31f2-4837-a9d3-5241d372c4e2
            <Value>-1;#Term B21|1e4d2d7b-19ab-4d82-9ab5-62f7f02c355c</Value>
            <Value>-1;#Term B22|2908460c-a16b-42dc-ac93-55f5f7cd83c9</Value>
        </Value>
    </Value>
    <Value>-1;#Term C|9bccd99c-c957-4d1a-a0c9-fef3e7ad0140</Value>
</Field>
<Field DisplayName="...">...
```

You can modify it to have what you need, in this case the code get the information to connect to the term store from a field, but if you already have it yo can avoid the field part:

```
public static List<XElement> GetTaxonomyFieldsXElements(ClientContext pContext, List<TaxonomyField> pFields)
{
    List<XElement> lFieldsXElements = new List<XElement>();
    TaxonomySession lTaxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(pContext);

    foreach (TaxonomyField lTaxField in pFields)
    {
        XElement lXField = new XElement("Field");
        lXField.Add(new XAttribute("DisplayName", lTaxField.Title));
        lXField.Add(new XAttribute("Type", lTaxField.TypeDisplayName));
        lXField.Add(new XAttribute("InternalName", lTaxField.InternalName));

        Guid lTermStoreId = lTaxField.SspId;
        Guid lTermSetId = lTaxField.TermSetId;

        TermStore lTermStore = lTaxonomySession.TermStores.GetById(lTermStoreId);
        TermSet lTermSet = lTermStore.GetTermSet(lTermSetId);
        TermCollection lTermColl = lTermSet.Terms;

        pContext.Load(lTermColl, tms => tms.Include(t => t.Name, t => t.Id, t => t.TermsCount, t => t.Terms, t => t.IsAvailableForTagging));
        pContext.ExecuteQuery();

        if (lTermColl.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Term lTerm in lTermColl)
            {
                if (lTerm.IsAvailableForTagging)
                {
                    XElement lXValue = GetTermValueXElement(pContext, lTerm);
                    lXField.Add(lXValue);
                }
            }
        }

        lFieldsXElements.Add(lXField);
    }

    return lFieldsXElements;
}

private static XElement GetTermValueXElement(ClientContext pContext, Term pTerm)
{
    XElement lXValue = new XElement("Value");
    lXValue.SetValue(string.Format("-1;#{0}|{1}", pTerm.Name, pTerm.Id.ToString()));

    if (pTerm.TermsCount > 0)
    {
        pContext.Load(pTerm, t => t.Name, t => t.Id, t => t.TermsCount, t => t.Terms, t => t.IsAvailableForTagging);
        pContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Term lInnerTerm in pTerm.Terms)
        {
            if (lInnerTerm.IsAvailableForTagging) //this is not necesary
            {
                XElement lXInnerValue = GetTermValueXElement(pContext, lInnerTerm);
                lXValue.Add(lXInnerValue);
            }
        }
    }

    return lXValue;
}
```